# VB NET Object Oriented

Tags: vb.net, oop

I'm a little new to classes on VB.NET (and to whole OOP concept in general) so sorry in advance for my poor explanation.
I've created a class like so:

```
Public Class MyApp

private var1 as integer = 2

Private Function getProfile(id As Integer)
    'Imaginary server request according to ID
    'Following that was received:
    Dim name As String = "John"
    Dim age As integer = 30
End Function

End Class
```

I want to be able to call getProfile by using myApp.getProfile and that's something I can handle.
What I can't manage is displaying only the age or name.
Something like this:

```
MyApp.getProfile(4341).age
```

How can I achieve something like this? Like having sub-functions in a function.

Comment: You need another class with a Name and an Age property.  Return an object of that class from your Function.

Comment: You seem to be fundamentally confused.  A method does not have properties.  A class (or instance of) does.  Therefore, you could have two methods like getAge and getName instead.  Perhaps do some more reading on OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the method that way it needs to be static (marked `Shared`) and public. To make it return the name and age as properties you need a class with those properties. Example:

```
Public Class MyApp

  Public Shared Function GetProfile(id As Integer)
    Dim name As String = "John"
    Dim age As integer = 30
    return New ServerResult(name, age)
  End Function

End Class

Public Class ServerResult

  Public Name as String
  Public Age as Integer

  Public Sub New(n as String, a as Integer)
    Name = n
    age = a
  End Sub

End Class
```

Usage example:

```
Dim age as Integer = MyApp.GetProfile(42).Age
```

Another:

```
Dim result As ServerResult = MyApp.GetProfile(1337)
Dim info As String = String.Format("{0}, {1}", result.Name, result.Age)
```

Note: Making the method static is based on how you wanted to call it. You might want to create an instance of the `MyApp` class instead, and have a method that is not static.